# How to unit test for exception in threads

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I need to unit test that an exception in raised in code like:

```
def test
  assert_raise Timeout::Error do
    Thread.new {
      raise  Timeout::Error
    }
  end
end
```

How to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

in the assert_raise block:

```
t = Thread.new { raise Timeout::Error }
t.join
```